# How to rollback database migration on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just deployed some code and database changes to Heroku and I would like to roll it back. I do have the releases add-on and was able to roll back the code but not the database. I didn't backup the database so I can't do a restore. I tried "heroku rake db:rollback" but it didn't do anything. Anyone knows?

Comment: your db:rollback works on local ?

Comment: Just rolling back on your local machine, then doing another heroku rake db:migrate doesn't work?

Comment: John Beynon is correct. Rollbacks do not bring back data. Only the DB schema is changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to run `heroku rake db:rollback` while the updated code that has the `.down` migration is deployed to Heroku. After that, you can rollback the *code*.

Comment: This was the missing step, there was no migration to rollback to seeing that I rollback the code already, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

db:rollback will rollback the last migration file that was executed - are you sure this hasn't been performed? If you're able to identify the number of migrations that you want to rollback for your deployment you can do

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```

which runs the down method in your last 3 migrations - this is of course if you've coded the down migration to revert exactly what was done in the up migration :)