# How to restore database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I was having some issue running

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate.
```

To resolve it, I did

```
$ heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

and all of my data was removed from the app. Then I realized that I had no pg backup :(
My database on heroku shows 7.7 MB size. Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: have you tried this `heroku rake db:rollback`
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942622/how-to-rollback-database-migration-on-heroku

Comment: tried it but no luck :(

Comment: My data from the database is removed.

Comment: check this article it might help you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection#physical-backups-on-heroku-postgres

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Heroku. The fact you see the size is still 7.7 MB is not a guarantee that you can recover the data as PG may not have run the vacuum process yet (and reset the statistics).

Your best chance is to contact Heroku as soon possible and check with them.

Comment: I've already contacted them, they will respond after 9 hours :(

Answer (score 0):

Your data may not be lost.

Did you identify the failing migration(s) ? You should try to resolve locally your migrations and push again. Then, the schema will be updated. 
The schema don't have any influence on the data stored, it is only useful for you as a document, and when running tests to populate the DB.

In an immediate action, you should try to use the `rake db:rollback STEP=x` where X is the number of migrations you want to rollback (Rollback as many times as the numbers of failing migrations, *but be careful, it is destructive !*) Then, you can rollback your application (not your database) from the Heroku Dashboard. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Edit : You should also try to look at the logs to see if anything seems wrong.
`heroku logs --app YOURAPP`
and `heroku logs -t --app YOURAPP`